# Is the automatic low quality answer comment unfit for Code Review?

Tags: discussion, answers, review, comments, low-quality-posts

This is the comment made on my behalf when I recommended deletion on an answer in the VLQ queue:

> This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

As the answerer pointed out, though, Code Review answers *are* the place to critique.

Does this text need rewriting to clarify intent?

Comment: I'm guessing this can be addressed, now that the site's design is in works and we've just about to full-on graduate.

Comment: Interesting question, I assume that this message is baked into network-wide configurations though... As such it would probably be a significant effort to change this only for Code Review

Comment: This has been bugging me too. Thanks for the reminder, we (the mods) should go and bug some people about this ;-)

Comment: I believe it means "critique the question", but could perhaps be clarified.

Comment: This question needs another answer, one not written by the author of the answer in question.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, I strongly believe it does needs to be rewritten for the Code Review community, because:

> Code Review is a question and answer site for seeking peer review of your code. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. We're working together to improve the skills of programmers worldwide by taking working code and making it better.

As you can see, that is what Code Review is about, and if you noted *by taking working code and making it better*, it does require the people who answer to provide critiques to the question author's code. But as @Mat'sMug stated, our site design is in the works, so I think we can give some time to the developers to fix it.

Comment: The site design is completely irrelevant about this, and you don't really provide another suggestion for how to change it.